# Obtener atributos de una clase en Python

Tags: python, poo, script

estoy desarrollando un script en **Python** que contiene una función que toma como argumento una clase (sin instanciarla) y devuelve los **atributos de instancia** de esa clase, es decir, el nombre de cada uno y el tipo de dato si esta especificado. Pero no logro crear esta función por completo. He investigado con inspect o con variables especiales de las clases (como **annotations**), pero me devuelven una lista vacía. Pondré un código de ejemplo para ilustrar la situación:

```
class MiClase():
    """
    Esta es mi clase.
    """
    def __init__(self, nombre: str):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.edad = 12
        self.verdad = True
    
    def saludar(nombre: str): 
        "Este método saluda."
        print(f"Hola, soy {nombre}")

def obtener_atributos_clase(clase):
     #Logica para devolver los atributos de instancia de la clase
     #Salida deseada con obtener_atributos_clase(MiClase): ("nombre: str, edad": int, verdad: bool")
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

**Tldr:** inspect.get_annotations y el atributo annotations funciona cuando el programador escribe en el código que atributos y tipos espera que aparezcan en la instancia. Recurrir a esto es la mejor forma desde mi punto de vista, ya que python, como lenguaje dinamico, no tiene prefijados los atributos ni los tipos.

##### Explayandose un poco sobre el tema

Nota inicial: Cuando mencione Builtin, al igual que dicen en inspect, me referiré a "hecho en c"

**Por que es imposible**

No es posible conocer los atributos de una clase sin instanciarla (al menos, las clases no builtins), y mucho menos conocer los atributos que tendrá en un futuro.
Esto es debido a que Python es un lenguaje dinamico, y las clases no tienen "prefijados" los atributos que aparecerán ni sus tipos. Además, de que la instancia (si no es un builtin) puede adquirir nuevos atributos "en tiempo de ejecución"

**Las anotaciones**

Por otro lado, lo que querés obtener, las anotaciones, son una ayuda **opcional** que deja el programador especificando de que atributos, variables y tipos **se espera** que existan. Aún así, diría que es en muchos casos es la opción más precisa. Usar inspect.get_annotations o el atributo annotations (esto ultimo no recomendado) funciona cuando dichas anotaciones existen, de lo contrario, no hay nada que obtener.

**Analizando el código**

Se puede obtener del código de la clase [un arbol de sintaxis abstracta](https://docs.python.org/es/3.11/library/ast.html), y escribir un algoritmo que pueda "**predecir**" los posibles atributos de una instancia. Esto es más complejo y no tendría una precisión del 100%. Una vez detectados los atributos explicitos, me surgen las siguientes dudas:

- ¿Cómo detectamos el uso de setattr y otras formas dinamicas de crear atributos sobre la instancia?
- ¿Cómo sabemos si un método aparentemente de instancia en realidad está pensado para usarse como de clase?
- Y si en realidad la clase no "puede" formar instancias (Este caso es posible debido a las metaclases)

Y quien sabe cuantos más posibles escenarios que hagan propenso a fallas dicho algoritmo.

Answer (score 0):

"*...toma como argumento una clase (sin instanciarla) y devuelve los atributos de instancia de esa clase...*" Eso se lee como (y es) una contradicción.

No puedes imprimir los atributos de instancia si no has instanciado a la clase:

```python
>>> print(dir(MiClase))
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', 
'__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getstate__', '__gt__', 
'__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', 
'__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__',
 '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'saludar']
>>>
>>> print(MiClase.__dict__)
{'__module__': '__main__', '__doc__': '\n    Esta es mi clase.\n    ', 
'__init__': <function MiClase.__init__ at 0x000001BA2FC58E00>, 
'saludar': <function MiClase.saludar at 0x000001BA2FC58F40>, 
'__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'MiClase' objects>, 
'__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'MiClase' objects>}
>>>
>>> # *** Instanciando la clase ***
>>> obj = MiClase('Maria')
print(dir(obj))
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', 
'__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getstate__', '__gt__', 
'__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', 
'__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__',
 '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__',
 'edad', 'nombre', 'saludar', 'verdad']
>>>
>>> print(obj.__dict__)
{'nombre': 'Maria', 'edad': 12, 'verdad': True}
```

Comment: No es tan contradictorio como piensas, en lenguajes como Java, que es estatico, el programador está obligado a especificar que campos (atributos) y tipos va a tener la instancia, los cuales SIEMPRE tienen un valor. Y por lo tanto, usando una forma de analisis en tiempo de ejecución conocida como "relexión" es posible conocer los atributos que va a tener toda instancia de esa clase, aunque no se puede saber exactamente que subtipos tendría.